# Reference $(SolutionDir) in resource file VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to build a solution which contains two projects:

1. COM Dll
2. Application using this DLL

In the COM dll, I'm trying to embed the `tlb` generated from the `idl` in the project. I have usual configuration `Debug-Release` and `Win32-x64` pair. Now, depending on this, the `tlb` file is created in different path which can be referenced via `$(SolutionDir)Project1\$(IntDir)`. How do I make my resource file reference this file each time I build with different configuration pair? Here's part of my `.rc` file:

```
#include <windows.h>

1 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE
BEGIN
"1 TYPELIB ""CalcCOMObject.tlb""\r\n\0"
END

// More info block code...

#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
// Please suggest in the line below:
1 TYPELIB "x64\\Debug\\CalcCOMObject.tlb"
#endif
```

I'd prefer if the resource file would still be editable in the `resource editor`. I'm using VS2015 to build my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `/I $(SolutionDir)Project1\$(IntDir)` to RC.EXE; in Visual Studio properties this can be found under "Resources>Additional Include Directories"

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.